# Flutter: give Map to Routes option from other file

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm a bit at loss here.

```
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Title',
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: SOMETHING_HERE,
    );
```

I want to push SOMETHING_HERE from a different file, but I can't seem to push a correct value there.

Other file (attempt):

```
import '../screens/home.dart';
import '../screens/charts.dart';

class Routes {

  factory Routes(context) {
    Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)> _routes;
    _routes = {
      '/': (context) => ScreenHome(),
      '/charts': (context) => ScreenCharts(),
    };
    return _routes;
  }

}
```

This doesn't work cause it says:
`The argument type 'Routes' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, (BuildContext) → Widget>'`

OF course I can just pass a Map to this argument but I want to define my routes in a separate file.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had the same problem and found the solution.

You don't need to create a class, just create a `var` that equals your routes `Map`

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './custom_routes.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: customRoutes,
    );
  }
}
```

custom_routes.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/home.dart';
import '../screens/charts.dart';

var customRoutes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/': (context) => ScreenHome(),
  '/charts': (context) => ScreenCharts(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create any function with return of `Map<String, WidgetBuilder>`, here i will show how to do that with pass data to your routes class:

1- Create new file `routes.dart`, this full code (i used my custom variables like `serverToken`, `notifierThemeMode`) to fully explain the process:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/to/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:path/to/login_screen.dart';

class AppRoutes{

  // get initial route
  static getInitialRoute({String? serverToken}){
    return serverToken == null
        ? LoginScreen.routeName
        : HomeScreen.routeName;
  }

  // get all app routes
  static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getRoutes({
    required BehaviorSubject<ThemeMode?> notifierThemeMode,
    required BehaviorSubject<Locale?> notifierLocale,
  }){
    return {
      HomeScreen.routeName: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(
        notifierThemeMode: notifierThemeMode,
      ),
      LoginScreen.routeName: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(
        notifierLocale: notifierLocale,
      ),
  }
}
```

2- In `MaterialApp` widget call the previous functions:

```
MaterialApp(
   ...
   routes: AppRoutes.getRoutes(
            notifierThemeMode: _notifierThemeMode,
            notifierLocale: _notifierLocale
           ),
   initialRoute: AppRoutes.getInitialRoute(
            serverToken: _appServerToken
           ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**

### There is another way you can try if you wish

**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(                   
       initialRoute: LoginScreen.id,
         routes: route,
       );
    },
 }
```

Create your route dart file. No need to create a class

```
var route = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
   LoginScreen.id: (_) => const LoginScreen(),
   // call the classes
   Dashboard.id: (_) => const Dashboard(),
   // with value
   Dashboard.id: (_) => const Dashboard(value: ''),
};
```

If you don't use call by id. You can do that as well. Also you can pass values shown example